# Javascript confirmation message in Spring-MVC application

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I want to display a confirmation message before deleting any element in the application, I have:

```
<form:form name="formule" method="get" commandName="user"
    onsubmit="confirmDelete('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/delete_element')">       
     <form:input type="hidden" path="id" name="id" />
     <input type="submit" value="DELETE" />
</form:form>
```

the function :

```
function confirmDelete(delUrl) {
    if (confirm("Are you sure ?")) {
        document.location = delUrl;
    }
}
```

**and this is the controller :**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete_element", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getInfo(@ModelAttribute User user,@RequestParam("id") int id,ModelMap model) {
    userservice.DeleteUser(id);
    return "ViewName";
}
```

This is what I get : **the link of the function doesn't take me to the controller so nothing is happening, we can say that the request sent by javascript is not reaching the server**.. is it really hard to integrate anything in Spring MVC like that ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<form ... onsubmit="confirmDelete('${...}/delete_element')">
```

Add the `return` keyword to the `onsubmit` event along the reference to the `form`:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return confirmDelete(this, '${...}/delete_element')">
                    ^^^^^^---- added     ^^^^--- added
```

Also, `document.location` is read-only in some browsers. It is better to use `window.location`. Don't forget to add `return` so the `form` is submitted only when wanted:

```
function confirmDelete(delForm, delUrl) { // <--- changed here
    if (confirm("Are you sure ?")) {
        delForm.action = delUrl;          // <--- changed here
        return true;                      // <--- changed here
    }
    return false;                         // <--- changed here
}
```

Comment: no change :/ I can always see the URL in the adress bar but it's not sent to the controller. and i see no request in the console. thanks for reply

Comment: So when you click the `<input type="submit" value="DELETE" />`, the `confirmDelete()` is never called? Is that it?

Comment: No it's called and the function shows the alert. I click "Ok" then the page reload and the element is not deleted

Comment: unfortunately, the server gives an error ( Etat HTTP 400, the syntax of request is not correct) and i see in the adress bar this link : **/delete_element** it doesn't take the ID parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you need to tamper with the form action URL?

```
<c:url var="deleteUrl" value="/delete_element" />
<form:form method="get" commandName="user" action="${deleteUrl}"
         onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure?') ? true : false;">
```

Also why do you need to bind the `@ModelAttribute` and/or the `ModelMap`? You are not sending or setting any user data so you might just ommit that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "delete_element", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getInfo(@RequestParam("id") int id) {
```

And a little off-topic: you **should not be using** HTTP `GET` method for modifying requests.  http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#submit-format

Comment: Thank you !! that  was very easy ! you mean I should always use POST ?

Comment: GET is meant for requests which don't modify server state (e.g. change something in database). `POST`s are more secure as the parameters are not being logged in access logs and browsers have replay protection (when hitting refresh, you are always asked for confirmation). Also it is a little bit easier to do XSRF attacks for GETs.

Comment: I've just noticed I've missed `action` attribute in my answer... updated (also added `<c:url>` for rendering the URL as that is the correct way how to do it).

Comment: `return confirm('Are you sure?') ? true : false;` could be just replaced with `return confirm('Are you sure?')`. Also this didn't quite worked for me - the form get submitted without showing the confirmation message. So I just put it with `onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"` to the submit button.